# bytes missing after pyspark writes to file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use pyspark to load a text file, sort it, and then write the sorted data to a different text file.

I have a simple script that correctly reads in the data, sorts it by key, then writes it to an output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print("Usage: ./sorter.py -i [input filename] -o [output filename]")
    sys.exit(1)

input_filename = sys.argv[2]

output_filename = sys.argv[4]

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .master("local[*]") \
                    .appName("sorter") \
                    .getOrCreate()

input_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(input_filename)

print("# partitions: {}".format(input_rdd.getNumPartitions()))

sorted_list = input_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[:10], x[:])) \
                        .sortByKey() \
                        .collect()

with open(output_filename, "w") as ofile:
    for line in sorted_list:
        ofile.write(line[1] + '\n')
```

The output file appears to be sorted correctly. However, the input is generated with `gensort` and the output validated with `valsort`, and when `./valsort output_file` is run my machine outputs

```
sump pump fatal error: pfunc_get_rec: partial record of 90 bytes found at end of input
```

I manually created a correct output file, and when I compare it to the pyspark-generated output file it finds no difference with `vimdiff`, thinks the files are completely different when I run `diff` and outputs

```
output/spark_output.txt output/correct_output.txt differ: byte 99, line 1
```

when I run `cmp` on them

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Great that you're asking questions and even sharing the solution! Could you, however, post the solution as an answer and mark your question as complete? This helps maintaining the quality of our beloved Stackoverflow! :)

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or change your question into an answer. Feel free (in fact, strongly encouraged) to post an actual answer with your solution, and accepting it to properly mark the question as resolved (or, of course, accept another answer if that's what got you on the right track).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gensort appends a carriage return (a.k.a `\r` and `^M`) to the end of every line, and these are somehow not captured when the input file is read in. Problem is solved with this code:

```
ofile.write(line[1] + '\r\n')
```